# How do I stop SkyDrive events from appearing in my Messenger feed?

Tags: windows-live-messenger

I have these "edited a file" and "share a photo" events in my messenger feed that I dont want to appear there.

How can I turn them all off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can goto this page to change your settings - http://profile.live.com/WhatsNewWithYouSettings